# Update column with distinct values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I created an employee table with columns (pk) emp_id and emp_name. I have a log table with the fields Employee Number and Employee Name.

I am trying to populate my table with records from the log where the emp_id is the unique identifier.However the data from the log contains duplicated Employee numbers and sometimes Missing Employee names.

I tried populating with just the Employee number and then updating the names where there are found but I am getting an error Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, etc.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblEmployee ON    
    Insert into tblEmployee (emp_id)        
    Select  Distinct [Employee Number]        
    From       
    wrkLogs        
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblEmployee OFF   

    Update tblEmployee        
    Set emp_name = (Select [Employee Name] 
                    From wrkLogs
                    Where emp_id= [Employee Number] AND LEN ([Employee Name] ) >1 
                    )        
    WHERE EXISTS (Select [Template Name] 
                    From wrkLogs
                    Where emp_id= [Employee Number ]AND LEN ([Employee Name] ) > 1  ) ;
```

Can anyone give me a better way to populate the table with all the distinct Employee numbers and the Employee Names where they are found. I think the problem is the data sometimes has the Employee Number accompanied by a blank Employee name but I still want those records in the table.I'm new to sql server and may be over thinking this.

Comment: You say "new to mysql" but have tagged with sql-server. Good idea to clarify which database you're using.

Comment: Sorry I meant sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find distinct employee number and available name, you can use [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) ranking function

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.employee ON
;WITH cte AS
 (      
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Employee Number] ORDER BY [Employee Name] DESC) AS rn
  FROM dbo.wrkLogs
  WHERE LEN([Employee Name]) >= 1
  )  
  INSERT dbo.employee(emp_id, emp_name)
  SELECT [Employee Number], [Employee Name]
  FROM cte
  WHERE rn = 1
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.employee OFF
```

Comment: This is what I wanted with a few tweaks Thanks!

Comment: bingo!glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the id|name combinations from the source table where the id appears only once:

```
 select id, name from source
 where name is not null and name <> ''  -- use trim() too if appropriate
 group by id having count(name) = 1
```

and assuming your target table is empty you can just insert those rows.

You can then remove those inserted rows from the source table.

What remains after that in your source table are the ids that appear there more than once, and names that are null, and they have to be cleaned up first, i.e. reduced to a set of unique (id,name) combinations.  How to do that would depend on the varieties of garbage in the source table (e.g. nulls, zero-length strings, leading/trailing spaces, misspellings and corrections, exact duplicates, etc).

P.S. substitute the appropriate column-names for your source table.

Comment: Thanks but the result isn't what I want. I essentially want all the distinct employee numbers and Employee names where available. Sometimes the Number is duplicated without a name.The most important part is the distinct ID

Comment: "Sometimes the number is duplicated without a name". The approach abov handles this -- it excludes rows without a name BEFORE the grouping with the HAVING clause.  If there are duplicated numbers with different names, that it does not handle. That is a problem that a query won't solve, except arbitrarily.